# boost::mutex::lock exception with error number 22

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, ace, boost-mutex

i am working with boost::mutex class to synchronize 2 threads on one resource.
i get an exception when i call the following `boost:mutex:lock()` function:

```
lock()
{
   int const res=pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
   if(res)
   {
      boost::throw_exception(lock_error(res));
   }
}
```

res = 22 which is EINVAL.
when i look at the man page of `pthread_mutex_lock` i can see that the function will not EINVAL in the following cases:

> EINVAL:
>   The value specified by mutex does not refer to an initialized mutex object.

this option is not relevant since boost:mutex constructor initializes the pthread_mutex_t.

> EINVAL:
>   The mutex was created with the protocol attribute having the value PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT and the calling thread's priority is higher than the mutex's current priority ceiling.

this option is much more reasonable. 
when you look at the initialization of the pthread_mutex_t in the boost::mutex custructor you see:

```
mutex()
 {
   int const res=pthread_mutex_init(&m,NULL);
   if(res)
   {
       boost::throw_exception(thread_resource_error());
   }
 }
```

that means that boost use the default `pthread_mutexattr_t` for the mutex.
my question is:

1. does the default value of the `pthread_mutexattr_t` includes protocol attribute having the value PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT ?
2. if you, my problem gets worst, since i depend on the thread priority that tries to lock the mutex. my thread is created by `ACE_Task_Base::activate`. can you tell me what is the ace default thread priority ?

i am running on linux redhat...